# Grab Yes/No after a particular word in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a huge text document lets say of 1000's of words and with way too many lines in the text.

I want to grab specific value of a particular word. In my example word is `Teetotlar` and value is `Yes` or `No`

**Sample text:**

> I am going to a party with my friends. I have lot of friends. they are
>   all coming to party. I will be happy to see each of them.
>
> Many of my friends drink but if you ask them r you teetotlar, they
>   would probably reply yes.
>
> But it is all good.

**I have working code for:**

1. Read all lines one by one
2. Check for teetotlar word
3. Again check if that have "Yes" or "No" and then save that value in one variable

**What I want:**

Is to have a **regex** which just checks for the word `Teetotlar` in the whole text and then looks for value `Yes` or `No` in the same line.

Comment: `\bTeetotlar\b.*\b(Yes|No)\b` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Whv0PI/1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
line = "Many of my friends drink but if you ask them r you teetotlar, they would probably reply yes."

m = re.search( r'\bteetotlar\b.*\b(?:yes|no)\b', line, re.M|re.I|re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print "the line matches"
```

This would let you check the line for `teetotler` and `yes/no`, with the former occurring before the latter.

Comment: Instead of line, can I pass my whole text ?

Comment: You would need to give us more information.  Do you expect a report of which lines matched and which did not?  Or, do you want a single scan of all lines, with a report of whether one single line matched?

Comment: I want to grab Yes or No after teetotlar..that's it. Irrespective of which line, which paragraph it is coming

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Use DOTALL mode and my updated answer should work.

Comment: Only after teetotalar, I want to capture "Yes/No" not before that!! So yes order matters

Comment: Answer updated again.

Comment: On doing `print m.groups()` it isn't returning me anything

Comment: Just need to do `re.findall` instead of `re.match`. Thanks for your help and patience!!